# Transforming $y=f(x)$ to $y^2=f(x)$

Tags: graphing-functions, transformation

Given a graph $y=f(x)$, transformed to $y^2=f(x)$, how can I determine the gradient of the roots at $y=0$ and why? Take this graph as an example: 
[$y=f(x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hq8c.png) transforms into [$y^2=f(x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRDU2.png)

Particularly, the gradient at B and C are different. It was also said that gradient at B could be 0 instead.

Comment: What are B and C?

Comment: The points at which the graph cuts the x-axis. Its shown in the picture link.